# Title, Paragraph and a tags in web page don't look same as the psd design

Tags: html, css

Title, Paragraph and a tags in web page don't look same as the psd design. The title tracking value is -25 and letter-spacing I have used is -0.025em for title. I have used Cardo, a Google Font for title. I am checking the differences with perfect pixel extension in Google Chrome. There is an issue in the first and last line of the paragraph. Paragraph's alignment is set to justify last left. View the images in large for better understanding. You can view the character panels of title, paragraph and a tags of photoshop in the below images. In navigation I have used Lato Black and Light. Other info you will get in the images of character panels.

I want the Title, Paragraph and a tags look pixel perfect in webpage.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/alrahat123/pen/PoLdNOV)

The issues I am facing in webpage:
[image: The issues I am facing in webpage]

Navigation Character Panel in Photoshop:
[image: Navigation Character Panel in Photoshop]

Contact Us Character Panel in Photoshop:
[image: Contact Us Character Panel in Photoshop]

Title Character Panel in Photoshop:
[image: Title Character Panel in Photoshop]

Paragraph Character Panel in Photoshop:
[image: Paragraph Character Panel in Photoshop]

Paragraph Alignment Character Panel in Photoshop:
[image: Paragraph Alignment Character Panel in Photoshop]

Reserve Ticket Character Panel in Photoshop:
[image: Reserve Ticket Character Panel in Photoshop]

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/8.0.1/normalize.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cardo:wght@700&family=Lato:wght@300;400;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="custom_reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="responsive.css">
</head>
<body>
    
    <header>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row row-1">
                <div class="col col-lg-11">    
                    <nav class="menu">
                        <ul>
                            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Guides</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Flights</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>      
                </div>
                <div class="col col-lg-7">
                    <div class="contact-us right">
                        <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row row-2">
                <div class="col col-lg-7">
                    <div class="left-side">
                        <h2 class="title">Travel to your dream destination</h2>
                        <p class="p-1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipi scing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Quis ipsum sus pendisse ultrices gravida. </p>
                        <a href="#">Reserve Ticket</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col col-lg-11">
                    <div class="right-side img-container">
                        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/xUIyDXA.jpg" alt="Reserve Tickets" class="img-responsive" width="662" height="419">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
        </div>
    </header>
  
    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/vendors/js/html5shiv.js/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/vendors/js/selectivizr.js/selectivizr.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/vendors/js/respond.js/respond.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Home -->
    <script src="home.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

```
/* Start Custom Reset */

html,body,blockquote,code,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,pre{margin:0;padding:0}
button,fieldset,form,input,legend,textarea,select{margin:0;padding:0}
fieldset{border:0}
a,a *{cursor:pointer}
div{margin:0;padding:0;background-color:transparent;text-align:left}
hr,img{border:0}
applet,iframe,object{border:0;margin:0;padding:0}
button,input[type=button],input[type=image],input[type=reset],input[type=submit],label{cursor:pointer;}
ul,li{list-style:none;margin:0;padding:0;}
strong{font-weight:bold;}
em{font-style:italic;} 

/* End Custom Reset */

/* style */

:root {
    --font-cardo: 'Cardo', serif;
    --font-lato: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
    font-size: 100%;
}

body {
    line-height: 1.2;
    background: #e9e7e7;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.title {
    font-family: var(--font-cardo);
    font-weight: 700;
}

.btn, a.btn, button.btn {
    font-family: var(--font-lato);
    font-weight: 900;
}

p {
    font-family: var(--font-lato);
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.2;
}

p.p-1 {
    font-size: 16.67px;
    letter-spacing: -0.025em;
}

p.p-2 {
    font-size: 16.66px;
    letter-spacing: -0.025em;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 12px;
    padding-right: 12px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.row {
    margin-left: -12px;
    margin-right: -12px;
}

.col {
    padding-left: 12px;
    padding-right: 12px;
    float: left;
}

.col-lg-1 {
    width: 5.55%;
}

.col-lg-2 {
    width: 11.1%;
}

.col-lg-3 {
    width: 16.65%;
}

.col-lg-4 {
    width: 22.2%;
}

.col-lg-5 {
    width: 27.75%;
}

.col-lg-6 {
    width: 33.3%;
}

.col-lg-7 {
    width: 38.85%;
}

.col-lg-8 {
    width: 44.4%;
}

.col-lg-9 {
    width: 50%; /* 49.95% */
}

.col-lg-10 {
    width: 55.5%;
}

.col-lg-11 {
    width: 61.05%;
}

.col-lg-12 {
    width: 66.6%;
}

.col-lg-13 {
    width: 72.15%;
}

.col-lg-14 {
    width: 77.7%;
}

.col-lg-15 {
    width: 83.25%;
}

.col-lg-16 {
    width: 88.8%;
}

.col-lg-17 {
    width: 94.35%;
}

.col-lg-18 {
    width: 100%; /* 99.9% */
}

*:after, .row:after, .cleafix:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
    height: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.left {
    float: left;
}

.right {
    float: right;
}

header {
    background: url('assets/images/header-bg.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center center;
    min-width: 1440px;
    height: 819px;
    padding-top: 79px;
    padding-bottom: 159px;
}

header .row-1 .menu {
    margin-top: 13px;
    margin-left: 55px;
}

header .menu ul li {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 78px;
    list-style: none;
}

header .menu ul li a {
    font-family: var(--font-lato);
    font-weight: 300;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20.83px;
    color: #515155;
    letter-spacing: -0.025em;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
} 

header .menu ul li.active a {
    font-weight: 900;
    color: #232323;
}

header .row-1 .contact-us {
    margin-right: 72px;
}

header .row-1 .contact-us a {
    font-family: var(--font-lato);
    font-weight: 900;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20.83px;
    letter-spacing: -0.025em;
    border: 3px solid #232323;
    border-radius: 6px;
    color: #232323;
    text-align: center;
    width: 218px;
    height: 54px;
    line-height: 45px;
}

header .row-2 {
    margin-top: 108px;
}

header .row-2 .left-side {
    width: 429px;
    margin-left: 54px;
}

header .row-2 .left-side h2 {
    font-size: 81.48px;
    line-height: 1;
    color: #232323;
    font-family: var(--font-cardo);
    font-weight: 700;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-left: 4px;
    letter-spacing: -0.025em;
}

header .row-2 .left-side p {
    color: #232323;
    font-family: var(--font-lato);
    font-weight: 400;
    margin-top: 19px;
    text-align: justify;
    text-align-last: left;
}

header .row-2 .left-side a {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: var(--font-lato);
    font-size: 20.83px;
    font-weight: 900;
    border-radius: 4px;
    width: 256px;
    height: 54px;
    line-height: 52px;
    background: #232323;
    color: #e9e7e7;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 4px;
    margin-top: 42px;
    letter-spacing: -0.025em;
}

header .row-2 .right-side {
    margin-left: 64px;
}

header .row-2 .right-side.img-container {
    width: 662px;
    height: 419px;
}

/* responsive */

@media screen and (min-width: 1440px) {
    .container {
        max-width: 1350px; /* 1326px */
    }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: There are several strategies for rendering fonts. PS lets you pick between some of them. Browsers do not (they only use one strategy). It looks you'll need to adjust font size and kerning to get your examples to match up better.

Comment: @Ouroborus Should I adjust it in PS or CSS? Does Figma and other softwares also have this problem?

Comment: I think if you change letter spacing it should mostly fix your issue (in PS, you have it set to -25). You'll never get pixel perfect matches across different software or platforms, but you can get close. The CSS option is [`letter-spacing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/letter-spacing).

Comment: Ensure you have loaded correct font. If your computer has some fancy font used in PS, that does not mean all clients will have in installed, so browser will fall back to e.g. Arial

Comment: @Ouroborus Paragraph's alignment is set to justify last left in PS. I have used text-align: jusitify; and text-align-last: left; in css. Is it correct?